# Paket include-referenced-projects with project references

Tags: nuget, paket

I have a solution that looks like this:

```
 -> Proj A
 -> proj B
```

`Proj B` references `Proj A`

Both projects have a `paket.template` that looks like this:

When I `paket pack`, I get two nugets created, one for each project. Fantastic.

However, I now want to make `ProjA.dll` be bundled inside `ProjB`'s nuget (`ProjB` is an .exe/tool that needs its dependencies bundled to operate).

Adding `include-referenced-projects true` to `ProjB`s `paket.template` has no effect, neither does any combination of `paket` command line `--include-referenced-projects true` that I've tried.

Is this supported? Is this a bug?

Either way, how can I achieve what I want, without making separate solutions to house `ProjA` and `ProjB`?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at ProjB.nuspec from resulting nuget package you see nuget reference to ProjA package. So resulting ProjB package has all needed dependencies.

You can achive what you want by several ways:

1. Pack ProjB by command `paket pack <output> --template <path to ProjB paket.tempplate>` (without `--include-referenced-projects` flag). Pack ProjA by separate command if you need it.
2. Delete `paket.template` from ProjA, then pack ProjB with `--include-referenced-projects` flag. But in this case package for ProjA will not be created.
3. Change paket.template type for ProjB from "project" to "file" and specify all dependencies and files manually.
4. (HACK:)) you can rename paket.template for ProjA from `paket.template` to `<somethingElse>.template` and pack ProjB with `--include-referenced-projects` flag. 
   Paket will not find than ProjA produce nuget package and add it as binary dependency to ProjB. You still can pack ProjA with separate command `paket pack --template "path to <somethingElse>.template"`